# Changing AWS registred domain back to AWS name servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, route53

Got into the issue with the AWS domain. Here is what happened:

1. Registered domain in AWS
2. Created Hosted Zone, configure GMAIL MX records
3. Changed name servers in AWS to point to the WIX NS
4. Deleted the WIX site
5. Changed name servers in AWS back to AWS name servers. (not the original ones, don't have them, using another AWS registered domain name servers)

Multiple problems now:

1. Domain is not resolving (dig, nslookup) - AWS reports ("..[205.251.196.25] rcode=REFUSED for ***")
2. AWS does not validate the certificate for this domain

- DNS validation creates records, but the certificate is stuck in pending state
- email validation also does not work, email is not sent to the registered domain owner address (check in promotions, spam etc, no email at all).

Thanks,
Regards,
Evgeny

Comment: Do you still have the old `AWS Hosted Zone` still in place or did you deleted that?

Comment: I deleted and recreated it as well, I still have old records from there.

Comment: If you have re-created the hosted-zone, set the Name Servers (4 of them) in your Route53 registered domain console. Do note that a change on Name Servers takes time to propagate. If the TTL (`Time To Live`) of the earlier NS records were not reduced, it may take hours to days to get it replaced with new entries. With DNS, we will have to be extra cautious. At this moment, we will have to be patient. To make sure that your new Hosted Zone's name servers are working right, run command "dig @<name-server> <one-record-in-hosted-zone>" . This should succeed first for this to work even with a wait.

Comment: That is the interesting bit - NS response is "..[205.251.198.138] rcode=REFUSED"

Comment: Why would AWS refuse to respond on NS lookup?

Comment: It will only respond if there is a hosted zone associated to them. The 4 aws assigned designated name servers only will respond correctly. Sending to random aws name servers won't work

Comment: They do... I have 3 domains in AWS, 12 NS servers... I checked, and they all responded for all domains, except one that was out and back in.

Comment: I have 2 domains in AWS with respective name servers. Using the Name Server for another hosted zone is giving me `status: REFUSED`. This is what is expected and since your concern is not on why others are responding, recommending below:

1) Check the new hosted zone
2) Click to expand "Hosted zone details" to see the designated 4 names servers,
3) Make sure that the NS entry in your hosted zone is pointing only at these 4

Comment: if you think a lot of change happened and not able to backtrack, proceed to create a new Public Hosted Zone. Don't make any change to the default NS and SOA record. Copy the NS entries and edit your domain registration page to point at these. Wait for it to get propagated. In the meantime, create the records to make it ready

Comment: OK, making progress, thanks. I ended up requesting all AWS NS servers for my domain and found 4 that are responding. Will set them and see how it goes. nslookup returns IPs, but dig still says REFUSED.

Comment: Thank you Halod for pointing out that not all NS servers respond on domains. It just happened to me that my particular ones worked. Once I found correct NS for my domains and updated them in domain name servers and hosted  zone file, all started to work.

Comment: Happy to see that its getting fixed :) . You may see some intermittent failures for next 48 hours which is normal with DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Halod for the hint.

Here is a piece of code to lookup domain name across all AWS NS servers

```
[TestClass]
public class AWSDomainRecovery
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Recover()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var list = await client.GetStringAsync("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/otsuka752/993b1851d5772f72c161effb6eb1a23e/raw/1ec4bb40c9a67f93386f69a38047f195dff499c6/list_ns-of-R53");
        var nameServers = list.Split("\n").Select(l => l.Trim().Split("\t")[1].Trim());
        
        var responding = new List<string>();            
        var domain = "<<YOUR DOMAIN HERE>>";

        foreach (var ns in nameServers)
        {
            var tld = Path.GetExtension(ns.TrimEnd('.'));
            if (responding.Any(r => r.Contains(tld)))
                continue;

            var args = $"{domain} {ns}";

            var info = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "nslookup",
                Arguments = args,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
            };

            var p = Process.Start(info);
            p.WaitForExit();
            var output = await p.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
            var error = await p.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error))
                responding.Add(ns);
        }
    }
}
```